# How could I reduce the duplicated haml code with if else condition

Tags: haml

it is hard to write if else in haml,

it will make the code looks nested and dirty.

Can i improve the following code more ?

```
  - user_agent = UserAgent.parse(request.user_agent)
  - if user_agent.mobile?
    .page-header
      %h4
        = get_route_title(@from, @to)
        %small
          = [t(@interval, scope: "flights"),
             t(@interval, scope: "flights.interval"),
             ].join(" ")
    - @line_charts.each do |line_chart_content|
      .row.presentation{:style => "padding-left:5px;"}
        = show_line_chart(line_chart_content)

  - else
    .page-header
      %h1
        = get_route_title(@from, @to)
        %small
          = [get_date_range(@start_date, @start_date+1.month),
             t(@interval, scope: "flights"),
             t(@interval, scope: "flights.interval"),
             ].join(" ")
    - @line_charts.each do |line_chart_content|
      .row.presentation{:style => "padding-left:99px;"}
        = show_line_chart(line_chart_content)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- user_agent = UserAgent.parse(request.user_agent)
  - content_for :my_part do
    = get_route_title(@from, @to)
        %small
          = [t(@interval, scope: "flights"),
             t(@interval, scope: "flights.interval"),
             ].join(" ")
    - @line_charts.each do |line_chart_content|
      .row.presentation{:style => "padding-left:5px;"}
        = show_line_chart(line_chart_content)
  - if user_agent.mobile?
    .page-header
      %h4
        = yield :mypart
  - else
    .page-header
      %h1
        = yield :mypart
```